# Difference between anonymous class and IDictionary<string,object> for htmlAttributes in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, idictionary

For example if you check these two extension methods the only difference is type of htmlAttributes so you can pass your htmlAttributes in two different ways:

```
public static MvcHtmlString TextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
    IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes);

public static MvcHtmlString TextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
    object htmlAttributes);
```

And use them in either of these ways:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TagLine,
    new { @placeholder = "We live to make art." })

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TagLine,
    new Dictionary<string, object> { 
        { "placeholder", "We live to make art." } })
```

I have checked MVC source code and I know in the background they use same method, but the one which accepts the anonymous object uses `HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes)` to make the anonymous object a dictionary.

In my point of view, views are cleaner to use anonymous object. What do you think guys? Are there any drawbacks to using an anonymous object?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's not too much difference, however using the anonymous object is a cleaner and more readable syntax for the caller, and now considered more standard practice.  There might be a slight, negligible performance benefit to using IDictionary if you're a fan of micro-optimisation.

The IDictionary overload option has probably stuck since ASP.NET MVC 1.0 CTP days when C# 3.0 and anonymous objects were still quite new.  Eilon Lipton's blog post proposing [Using C# 3.0 Anonymous Types as Dictionaries](http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2007/09/24/using-c-3-0-anonymous-types-as-dictionaries.aspx) gives some background.

Comment: The dictionary overloads are useful in some cases where you already have a dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

Chris answers all the thing.

I give 1 more reason why use IDictionary: Prior to MVC 3.0, you could not use anonymous object when you need a HTML5 attribute like "data-something" :D

Cheers

Comment: You can use this with underscore , like : @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TagLine,
    new { data_as_multiple = "true" })

Comment: From MVC 3.0 onwards you can use an underscore, e.g. `new { data_something = "value" }`, which will automatically be converted to a dash `data-something="value"`

Answer (score 2):

The `IDictionary<string, object>` is there for a special reason. If you want to adjust the htmlAttributes parameter in a extended function then this is possible. I have several extensions of the `Html.TextBox` function. I have for example a function thats called: `TextBoxOrDisplayForNoDiaCritics`. This function enables a TextBox or displays a disabled textbox. Additional it also removes DiaCritics from the textbox. I do this with a Javascript function. The event `onchange` fires on the input tag. So in this function I add that onchange event with the javascript function name to the htmlAttributes list. If I use a IDictionary thats easy but when I use an object that will be much harder.

So when you start your project its important to recognize what purpose your Html Helpers have to serve. In my case because I recognize the importance in my project I use IDictionary everywhere in my Project.

Comment: This is exactly what I am trying to do.  Do you pass in a dictionary object from your views (syntax is not as clean as passing in an anonymous object)?  Or, if you pass in an anonymous object, how do you convert it to a dictionary so you can add additional attributes?  Of course this is possible with reflection but this seems like a common enough scenario that I think they would have built a helper method in MVC for doing this conversion, but I haven't found it so far

Comment: this is how I pass, does not look so clean but works:  @Html.TextBoxWhenEmptyFor(model => model.UAccount, new Dictionary<string, object> { { ModelConstants.Style, ModelConstants.WidthMinZoekButton } }) another way:  @Html.Partial("_LogoHeading", new { Logo = "Applicaties", Link = "Applicaties" }.ToExpando() ) because I want to pass properties and thats something that is otherwise not possible dynamically.