# Errors when i try to provide an anonymous class to IDictionary

Tags: c#

I have been following this question on how to use anonymous for `IDictionary` since it provides a cleaner and compact code solution.

[Difference between anonymous class and IDictionary<string,object> for htmlAttributes in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8160275/difference-between-anonymous-class-and-idictionarystring-object-for-htmlattrib)

When i was trying to test how it works, i get the following errors from my compilter:

```
(23:13) The best overloaded method match for 'Rextester.Program.test(System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string,string>)' has some invalid arguments
(23:18) Argument 1: cannot convert from 'AnonymousType#1' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<object,string>'
```

Here is my code:

```
namespace Rextester
{
  public class Program
  {        
     public static void test(IDictionary<object,string> carl){}       

     public static void Main(string[] args)
     {
        test(new{carl="Hello", carl2="World"});
     }
   }
 }
```

Can someone tell me what am i doing wrong? I even copy pasted the code from the other SO but i still keep on getting the same error.

**Compiler:** I am at school so I am just using an online compiler.

Comment: `new{...}` is not an `IDictionary`

Comment: Why does it work here? http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/using-c-3-0-anonymous-types-as-dictionaries

Comment: It doesn't. "My proposal: Have the method accept a parameter of type object." - he changed the method to accept object instead of IDictionary.

Comment: @CarloBrew it doesn't, the author of that post didn't post the new prototype after he did this: *"Have the method accept a parameter of type object. "*... He changed the parameter from dictionary to object.

Comment: oh right it can't. Alright thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MVC does not convert an anonymous object to an `IDictionary`.  Notice that there are two methods in the linked question:

```
public static MvcHtmlString TextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
    IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes);

public static MvcHtmlString TextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
    object htmlAttributes);
```

The last parameters to the first method is an `IDictionary<string, object>` while the last parameter to the second method is `object`.  When you pass an anonymous object to `TextBoxFor` it is the second method that is called since an `anonymous object` can be converted to `object`, but not `IDictionary<string, object>`.  It would then use reflection to get the properties and values defined on the anonymous type.

See [In c# convert anonymous type into key/value array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481923/in-c-sharp-convert-anonymous-type-into-key-value-array) for how to convert an anonymous type to and `IDictionary<string, object>`.

Comment: So if i have something like `public static string Label(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string forName, string labelText,
                               IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)` then i must pass it as strictly `Dictionary` only ?

Comment: Yes you can only pass a `Dictionary<string, object>`  for `htmlAttributes` to that method.  But you can have a separate method `public static string Label(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string forName, string labelText, object htmlAttributes)` that you could pass an anonymous type to.

Comment: Argh im so slow, totally forgot about reflection. I can just convert the anonymous and redirect it to the one with IDictionary. Did i get the idea correct?

Answer (score 1):

According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx:
"Anonymous types are class types that derive directly from object, and that cannot be cast to any type except object."

So I guess the compiler cannot cast it to IDictionary<> for the method call, which is what the compiler tells you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public static void test(IDictionary<object, string> carl)
        {


        }


        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            test( new Dictionary<object,string>{{"Hello", "World"}});
        }​
```

Comment: yeah i think that's the only probable solution, to make a new `Dictionary`. Thank you.