# How to correctly parse Dictionary<string, object> into

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dictionary, anonymous-objects

I was working on `HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes`.

It works well with anonymous object:

```
var test = new {@class = "aaa", placeholder = "bbb"};
var parseTest= HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(test);
```

The result `parseTest` has two key-value pairs.

But for `Dictionary` object:

```
var attrsInDict = new Dictionary<string,object>() {            
    {"class", "form-control"},
    {"placeholder", "Select one..."}
};
var attrs = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(attrsInDict );
```

The `attrs` obtained is a strange object, with 4 Keys and 4 Values. The 4 keys are **Comparer**, **Count**, **Keys**,**Values**.

Some other SO post asking about the difference between the two([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8160275/difference-between-anonymous-class-and-idictionarystring-object-for-htmlattrib)). The selected answer says

> There's not too much difference...

Really? And what is the correct way to parse the `attrsInDict` and get the same result as the one we get from an anonymous object?

For, I intend to merge attribues in the following code:

```
var attributes = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);
foreach (var item in attrs)
{
    if (attr.ContainsKey(item.Key))
    {
        attr[item.Key] = $"{attr[item.Key]} {item.Value}";
    }
    else
    {
        attr.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The results are not strange -- they are exactly what I would expect from a method called `AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes`. The method expects input like `test`, an actual anonymous object, not an instance of concrete class like `Dictionary`.

What you're seeing in the case of passing an instance of `Dictionary` are its public properties, which are indeed the `Comparer`, `Count`, `Keys`, and `Values` properties.

The return type of `AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes` is `RouteValueDictionary`. That class has a constructor overload that accepts a `IDictionary<string, object>`.

To correctly use your dictionary, do this:

```
var attrs = new RouteValueDictionary(attrsInDict);
```

Comment: I see no difference between `new RouteValueDictionary(attrsInDict);` and `HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(attrsInDict);`. Both returned the same result. Anything I missed?

Comment: @Blaise: Those two examples are not the same; you should not pass a dictionary instance into the `HtmlHelper` method -- only anonymous objects. To get the same result from an anonymous object and a Dictionary instance, you need to use the two different approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Comparer, Count, Keys, and Values are public properties of class Dictionary. So you are getting exactly what you are requesting. If you want actual key-value pairs, you need to iterate over Dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

`AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes` method most probably uses reflection to iterate through public properties of the provided type. As seen in its [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx), the only properties besides the indexer are `Comparer`, `Count`, `Keys` and `Values`.